# recognizing packages in python IDLE after upgrading python version

Tags: python, pandas, pip, python-idle

I have upgraded my python version(3.9.6). I have problem of not being able to use pandas in idle cause it doesn't recognise it. so as always I use

```
import pip;
pip.main(["install","pandas"])
```

cause I always have problem finding the environment in which IDle is installed in IDLE itself but gives error

> WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
> Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
> To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.

so I checked [github link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599) but I was a general topic about pip in cmd not for using in pip by `pip.main(["install","pandas"])` in script. so my question is how to install pandas in Idle which maybe by 1. finding environment of IDLE then using pip in cmd or 2. fix `pip.main(["install","pandas"])`.
note that I have tried `pip.main(["install","--user","pandas"])` and also tried `import sys;print(sys.executable)` to find IDle's path and after that tried to chdir the directory in cmd to there then use 'pip install pandas' but didnt work.

Comment: IDLE shouldn't really be used for very serious work. You might want to consider some external IDE instead.

Comment: I always use it for my main long hour taking jobs. cause I dont know any ide for parallel.

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't know any IDE for parallel"? If you have a Python script you've written, you can run it in a separate terminal window?

Comment: I meant in Iphyton IDEs you can't run parallel and I generally use spyder and there I can't run parallel

Comment: Can't run what parallel? In Pycharm, which is what I use, you can run as many programs as you like in parallel...

Comment: I have never used pycharm, I don know why but I have a negative bias toward it!!! cause I have heard its heavy

Comment: Well, how about Visual Studio Code? It's leaps and bounds better than IDLE.

Comment: unfortunately or fortunately I dound the answer so probably I wouldn't use VSC soon.

Comment: general comment: so the title is suitable. it was really an issue of python version not environments. at least what I think now.

Comment: @AKX  Discussion of the merits of different editors and IDEs is explicitly and properly off-topic for stackoverflow.  Your opinionated and, in my opinion wrong, comment is an example of why.   I do 'very serious work' with IDLE.  Such discussion is specifically off-topic for this question since import errors and pip install problems have nothing to do with IDLE.  What Farhang needed was these two specific solutions: `pip3.9 install...` or `py -3.9 -m pip install...`.  Which will work depends on the OS and installation method and installation options.

Comment: @AKX I installed VSC and it gives longer process time than IDLE, maybe you should try IDLE. anyway thanx for your suggestions eventhough they seemed off topic, or in other words, general solution (by not using IDLE).

Comment: Your choice of IDE shouldn't affect the runtime of your code by very much. Anyway, glad you found your solution.

Comment: a bit more than twice, I was also shocked!16.4s v.s. 36.2s

Answer (score 0):

I tried `pip3.9 install pandas` and it did work.